# Node JS with axios async/await: write response to local file

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios

I'm developing a Node CLI app to use locally. It takes a CSV file as input, and based on the values in its userId column, it makes a GET request to an API using one of those values at a time as input. I've created a dummy example of this below.
Here is the axios request wrapped in an async function, which returns a Promise:

```
const axios = require("axios");
const utils = require("./utils");
const fs = require("fs").promises;

async function getTitleGivenId(id) {
  try {
    return await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

// This works fine
getTitleGivenId(1).then(res => {
  console.log(res.data.title);
});
```

I've come up with this in order to write a CSV, but the `allData` string doesn't get updated inside the `map` function:

```
async function saveTitles(inCsv, outCsv) {
  try {
    const arrOfObj = utils.readCsv(inCsv);
    // [
    //   { userId: '1', color: 'green' },
    //   { userId: '2', color: 'blue' },
    //   { userId: '3', color: 'red' }
    // ]

    let allData = "color,title\n";
    arrOfObj.map(o => {
      let title;
      getTitleGivenId(o["userId"]).then(res => {
        title = res.data.title;
        allData += `${o["color"]},${title}\n`;
      });
    });
    await fs.writeFile(outCsv, allData);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

// This writes only "color,title" to "outCsv.csv"
saveTitles("./inputCsv.csv", "./outCsv.csv");
```

Any suggestions/alternative ways to proceed would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets updated. You're just not waiting for it to be finished. The `map()` function is executed, but it will *not* wait for the promises inside to be finished. So one option is to make the map function `async` as well and just wait for all iterations to be finished:

```
let allData = "color,title\n";
await Promise.all( arrOfObj.map( async (o) => {
  const res = await getTitleGivenId(o["userId"])
  const title = res.data.title;
  allData += `${o["color"]},${title}\n`;
}) );
await fs.writeFile(outCsv, allData);
```

Comment: Legend, thanks. I've spent the whole weekend struggling with async/await.